# How to calculate the time difference between unix time stamps?

Tags: php

I am creating time stamps in PHP using **`time()`**;

I have the `$current_time` and `$purchase_time`. How do I make sure that purchase_time is less than 24 hours of current time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since UNIX timestamps are just numbers of seconds, just use the difference:

```
$purchasedToday = $current_time - $purchase_time < 24 * 60 * 60;
if ($purchasedToday) {
  echo 'You just bought the item';
} else {
  echo 'You bought the item some time ago';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If they are UNIX timestamps, then you can calculate this by yourself really easy, as they are seconds.

```
$seconds = $current_time - $purchase_time
$hours = floor($seconds/3600);
if ($hours < 24){
    //success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and then use it's [diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method to calculate the difference between $current_time and $purchase_time:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$purchaseTime = new DateTime('2011-10-14 12:34:56');

// Calculate difference:
$difference = $currentTime->diff($purchaseTime);

if ($difference->days >= 1) {
    echo 'More than 24 hours ago.';
}
```

This is more reliable than calculating the difference yourself, as this method takes care of timezones and daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$difference=time() - $last_login;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had use something like this:

```
<?php
if(date("U", strtotime("-24  hours", $current_time) > date("U", $purchase_time)) {
    echo "More then 24 hours you purchased this radio";
}
?>
```

This works even if the time stamp not is a UNIX-timestamp.